# jquery - split when integer or space is found (i.e. split course code)

Tags: javascript, jquery, join, split, splice

I have a list of course codes like:

```
CRS100
CRS301
CRS332
...etc.
```

I would like split these course codes so that I can do something like this:

```
<a data-courseProgram="CRS" data-courseCode="301">CRS301</a>
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Are all ids 6 in length?

Comment: yep, 6 characters. would also be nice to be able to account for a space between the course code, though. for example, account for 'CRS 301'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you want to do is split the ID into half as the first three letters are consistent, rest is the ID, so you can do something like,

```
var s = 'CRS332'; //course ID
var i = s.length / 2; //split the string into half
var course = s.substr(0, i); //gives you CRS
var courseId = s.substr(i);  //gives you 332
```

---

To have a more elegant solution, you can also use regex and split the string into half, like

```
var str = 'CRS332';
var splitId = str.match(/.{1,3}/g);
console.log(splitId); //outputs ['CRS', '332'];
```

Now, you can use the above one like `splitId[0]` and `splitId[1]` respectively.

---

If you have combination of ids like CRS332 and CRS 332 (with a space), you can use the following code (I just wrote and tested on fiddle, might miss corner cases which you have to handle)

```
//all ids, and create a new container to push the splitted ids
var dir = ['CRS 332', 'CRS447'], newDir = [];

//loop all the course ids
for(var i = 0, l = dir.length; i < l; i++) {

  //if space exists, split it   
  if(dir[i].indexOf(' ') !== -1) {
    //space exists in the string, do a normal split
    newDir.push(dir[i].split(' '));
  } else {
    //if no space, split it in half
    newDir.push(dir[i].match(/.{1,3}/g));
  }
}

console.log(newDir);
```

Comment: Also, your question is unclear, if you are saying that your course id can have space as well, just put and if condition which checks the length of the string, if it exceeds 6, it's pretty simple, you can use `'YOUR STRING'.split(' ')` and it will split up for you